# Why does the <xsl:template match="/"> throw an error when adding a <xsl:result-document>?

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

With this source XML:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<ns:Report_Data xmlns:ns="urn:someURN">
    <ns:Report_Entry>
        <ns:ReportName>SomeReportName</ns:ReportName>
        <ns:ReportComments>Some description for this report....</ns:ReportComments>
        <ns:AreaWhereUsed Descriptor="ThisIsATransform">
            <ns:ID type="GUID">SomeUniqueID</ns:ID>
            <ns:ID type="Component_ID">CUSTOM_COMPONENT</ns:ID>
        </ns:AreaWhereUsed>
        <ns:AreaWhereUsed Descriptor="SomeProcessName">
            <ns:ID type="GUID">SomeDifferentUniqueID</ns:ID>
            <ns:ID type="Process_ID">SomeProcessName</ns:ID>
        </ns:AreaWhereUsed>
        <ns:Area_Where_Used/>
        <ns:Area_Where_Used>
            <ns:AWU_Comment>This is some process description</ns:AWU_Comment>
        </ns:Area_Where_Used>
        <ns:CFs>
            <ns:CF>SomeCF</ns:CF>
        </ns:CFs>
    </ns:Report_Entry>
</ns:Report_Data>
```

I am trying to convert it to a set of text documents. One document for each "Report Entry."

When I use this XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:ns="urn:someURN"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:variable name="delimiter" select="'&#x09;'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="quote" select="'&#x22;'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="linefeed" select="'&#xA;'"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <!-- Data Row Begins -->
        <xsl:for-each select="/ns:Report_Data/ns:Report_Entry">

                <xsl:text>Text and various other stuffs</xsl:text>

        </xsl:for-each>
        <!-- Data Row End -->
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output is that single line of text, which I mostly expect.

However, when I add a `result-document` tag, like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:ns="urn:someURN"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:variable name="delimiter" select="'&#x09;'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="quote" select="'&#x22;'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="linefeed" select="'&#xA;'"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <!-- Data Row Begins -->
        <xsl:for-each select="/ns:Report_Data/ns:Report_Entry">
            <xsl:result-document method="text" href="file_{@ns:ReportName}-output.txt">
                <xsl:text>Text and various other stuffs</xsl:text>
            </xsl:result-document>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <!-- Data Row End -->
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I get the error: `Error: Internal error evaluating template rule at line 10 in module` which refers to the template line: `<xsl:template match="/">` I'm using the website http://xslttest.appspot.com/ for testing my transform.

I'm still pretty new to XSL, so I don't really understand what the template and apply-template tags do. I'd appreciate any pointers as to how the template tag is interacting with the result-document tag.

(Note, I've heavily sanitized the code, but it runs as stated above).

Thanks!

Comment: So you are using an online app where you expect to write out a file using `xsl:result-document`? Where do you expect the file to be written to? I would suggest to test in an environment (like your own system with an XSLT processor installed or an XML IDE installed) where you can be sure that your processor has the right to access the file system to write out results.

Comment: Sorry, I should add that I've also tried this in the target environment (which I'm told by the vendor supports this functionality), and it also produced a similarly vague error.

Comment: If the output format is supposed to be plain text, I wonder why you have `href="file_{@ReportName}-output.xml"` with `.xml`. I also wonder why you have the `@ReportName`, I think you want `ReportName` instead, as you only have an element of that name and not an attribute of that name.

Comment: And we really would need to see minimal but complete samples allowing us to reproduce the error, as I don't see how `/Report_Data/Report_Entry` would select anything give the default namespace `Report_Data xmlns="urn:(someURN)"` on your root element.

Comment: The file extension won't change the outcome. Please try to focus on the question asked. I've updated the code so that the first XSL runs properly and produces the output `Text and various other stuffs` The second XSL does not run, but produces an error at line 10, which is the line that reads `<xsl:template match="/">`

Comment: Can you also add the exact error you get when you test on the target system?

Comment: I tried your sample using Saxon 9.7 from the command line, it does not output any error and when using the `-t` option indicates it has written a file named `file_-output.txt`. If you had several input items I would then expect you to get an error on the `xsl:result-document` saying `Cannot write more than one result document to the same URI` as you have `href="file_{@ReportName}-output.txt"` and not `href="file_{ns:ReportName}-output.txt"`. Indeed that is the error I get when I edit the provided input sample and add a second `Report_Entry`.

Comment: Interesting... I'll update that namespace. I may have just overlooked it...

Comment: Even with the correct namespace in the file name it gives "Error: Internal error evaluating template rule at line 10 in module." The target system is even more vague: "Error transforming data. Please review your configuration."

Comment: Nevermind. It turns out that it's NOT supported on the target system. That's why it's failing. I talked to the wrong guy....

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is no namespace prefix used in the xpath in `<xsl:for-each select="/Report_Data/Report_Entry">`, but your input xml has it. So I doubt there is any output coming from your transformation.
You can specify a prefix for the namespace, `urn:(someURN)`, and must use the same prefix with elements in the xpath.
e.g., 
`xmlns:ns="urn:(someURN)"`
`<xsl:for-each select="/ns:Report_Data/ns:Report_Entry">`

The use of a website(an external resource) could be the issue while using `xsl:result-document` as this instruction would instruct the processor to write a local file, which might not be possible.
I suggest you to use a local processor and try the transformation.

Comment: The missing namespace is just an artifact of the sanitizing. It works properly without the result-document. I expected the website to just present the file as text, like it has the other output, but I suppose that could be an issue. Unfortunately, I've already tried this on the target system and it also generated some similarly generic error. I've been told that the target system supports this functionality in XSL 2.0 so I'm inclined to believe that the problem is with the implementing system installed between the keyboard and the chair.